# How to query activities that can execute Intent.ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT?

Tags: android, flutter, android-intent

I'm trying to make kinda custom selection toolbar usign flutter. The problem I'm trying to solve is that default flutter selection toolbar doesn't show, or event get from system, actions, that can be performed on texts.

I found that Intent.ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT is responsible for that actions.

I tried querying activities this way:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)

        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, "messenger/show_menu")
                .setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
                    run {
                        val packs: List<ResolveInfo>

                        val intent_int = Intent().apply {
                            action = Intent.ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT
                            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT, "sample text")
                            type = "text/plain"
                        }

                        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 33) {
                            packs =
                                    context.getPackageManager()
                                            .queryIntentActivities(intent_int, 131072)
                        } else {
                            packs =
                                    context.getPackageManager()
                                            .queryIntentActivities(
                                                    intent_int,
                                                    PackageManager.ResolveInfoFlags.of(
                                                            PackageManager.MATCH_ALL.toLong()
                                                    )
                                            )
                        }
                        result.success(packs) //packs is empty somehow 
                    }
                }
    }
}
```

but it results in packs being empty. I tried also without extras, data, end type, but result was the same. On the other hand, when changed Intent to ACTION_MAIN it populated packs with many activities.

I got profile/AndroidManifest.xml set as follows

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app">
    <!-- The INTERNET permission is required for development. Specifically,
         the Flutter tool needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>
```